# Custom Delegate is not calling from NSURLSessionDelegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession for service integration. While uploading an image in to server, I want to show the percentage of data that has been uploaded to server. For that, i created a custom delegate in my service model class, and calling this delegate inside NSURLSession's delegate. Please check my code below.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
NSLog(@" %lld    %lld    %lld %lu", bytesSent , totalBytesSent,totalBytesExpectedToSend,(unsigned long)task.taskIdentifier);

float dataSent = (totalBytesSent/totalBytesExpectedToSend);

NSLog(@"sent percentage : %0.2f",(dataSent * 100));
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//_delegate is my custom delegate
    [_delegate updateUploadedDataInfo:dataSent];
});
}
```

But, [_delegate updateUploadedDataInfo:dataSent] method is not calling here. 
Please suggest, where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure your delegate is not nil.

Comment: Also, did you try to call it outside from your request to see if it works?

Comment: @stefos, delegate is nil. can you please suggest how to fix this issue

Comment: and can you please say that, why my delegate is nil this time.

Comment: Did you definitely call [`sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsession/1411597-sessionwithconfiguration?language=objc) instantiating the NSURLSession and specifing its delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Just add your service model object as delegate. E.g assume your servcice model class is MyModel and your posted code is in another class MyDownloader. In your MyModel class add:

```
MyDonlowder *downlowder = [[MyDownloader alloc] init];
downlowder.delegate = self;
```

Also make your MyModel class conform to MyCystomDelegateProtocol and implement the required method `updateUploadedDataInfo`.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented it. But still i am getting this issue.

Comment: Your delegate object probably is deallocating. Keep strong reference to that object to keep it alive.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed this issue.